# Ошибка при отправке сообщения в discord с помощью aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, discord.py, discord

Код

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from states import Form
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

async def send_to_discord(message):
    channel_id = ###
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(message)

bot = Bot(token='###')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Здравствуйте")
    
    await send_to_discord("Пользователь отправил команду /start в Telegram")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
    client.run('###')
```

Ошибка

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\test1.py", line 37, in start
    await send_to_discord("Здравствуйте")
  File "c:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\test1.py", line 25, in send_to_discord
    await channel.send(message_text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Делаю бота который отправляет запросы и получает картинки от Midjourney.

UPD1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 320, in start_polling
    loop.run_until_complete(self._startup_polling())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 617, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 577, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\discordtest.py", line 51, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\discordtest.py", line 19, in main
    loop.create_task(executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True))
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 45, in start_polling
    executor.start_polling(
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 328, in start_polling
    loop.run_until_complete(self._shutdown_polling())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 617, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 577, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Executor._startup_polling' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Executor._shutdown_polling' was never awaited
```

Вот такая ошибка при использовании asyncio

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` указывает на то, что объект `channel` равен `None`. Это произошло, потому что функция `client.get_channel(channel_id)` не нашла канал с указанным `channel_id` и вернула значение `None`.

Вот несколько возможных причин этой ошибки и способов её устранения:

1. **Проверьте ID канала**: Убедитесь, что `channel_id` действительно существует и корректен.
2. **Bot не подключен к Discord**: Убедитесь, что ваш бот успешно подключился к Discord, прежде чем пытаться отправить сообщение в канал. Вы используете `client.run('###')`, но это блокирующая функция и она запускается только после того, как завершится `executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)`, что, скорее всего, не происходит. Это означает, что ваш бот никогда не подключается к Discord.

   Решение: Запускайте Discord бота и aiogram бота в разных потоках или используйте асинхронную библиотеку для работы с Discord, например, `discord.ext.commands.Bot`.
3. **Права доступа**: Убедитесь, что ваш бот имеет разрешение на чтение и отправку сообщений в целевом канале.

Чтобы решить проблему с одновременным запуском ботов, вы можете использовать `asyncio` для создания нескольких задач:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    # Запускаем aiogram бота в фоновом режиме
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True))
    
    # Запускаем Discord бота
    await client.start('###')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Убедитесь, что используете актуальные версии библиотек и соответствующую документацию для их использования.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)